# Rails 4 - can't find entity in join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have there model objects, `Team`, `Post`, `User` and a join table between `Team` and `User` called `Member`. Users in teams can vote on posts. When voting on a posts I want give the user who created the `Post` points. I therefore have a ´points integer`attribute in my`Member` model. I have a method where I give points to users which looks like this:

```
def give_points_to_user(post, increase)

  member = post.user.members.where(team_id: post.team.id).first

  if increase
    member.points += 5
  else
    member.points -= 5
  end

  member.save!

end
```

Calling this method gives me this error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

So, how should my find (or where) call look if I want to find the correct member? That is, the member/user who created the post.

Comment: Please post how the associations between the models are set up

Comment: Do you already have a `value` for `points` in the table? If not `member.points += 5` won't work because when you give `member.points += 5` it is actually `member.points = member.points+5`,so `member.points` would be nil,so is the error.

Comment: @Pavan Seems like you're right. I though the default values of integers would be 0. Not using += or -= made it work (no error at least).

Comment: you need make your field default to 0

Comment: How did you made it work? I'm curious to know.

Comment: Just tried to make a normal assignment to test it, `member.points = 5`. Will add more logic to make it behave as I want.

Comment: @Mandeep Thanks, will do that!

Comment: Hmm,good.Meanwhile i will write my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

The problem is the `points` value is initially set to nothing,so `member.points += 5` won't work because when you give `member.points += 5` it is actually `member.points = member.points+5`.So you are actually giving `member.points = nil+5`,which fails giving that error.

**Solution**

As,@Mandeep said,you could make it work by setting a default value to `points` attribute in the table.Suppose if the value is `zero(0)` then the result of `member.points += 5` would be 5.